# math notation in the `\section` part doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, section-titles

I'm getting error while I'm using this command in XeTeX:

```
\section{Henk Barendregt book on $\lambda$-calculus}
```

How can I fix it ?

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "lane2"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: lane2.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file lane2.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file lane2.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file lane2.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   makeindex.exe "lane2.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2021/W32TeX] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file lane2.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in lane2.ind.
Transcript written in lane2.ilg.


Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "lane2.ist" -t "lane2.glg" -o "lane2.gls" "lane2.glo"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

Index style file lane2.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcg] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]


Command Line:   latexmk -xelatex --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "lane2.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\Y

Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 20 November 2021, version: 4.76.
Rule 'xelatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'lane2.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 -recorder  "lane2.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lane2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (./kaobook.cls
Document Class: kaobook 2021/06/02 v0.9.7 kaobook
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.clo)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty)) (./kao.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/options/options.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpatch/xpatch.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/imakeidx/imakeidx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/varioref.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer-scrpage.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlayer.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyphenat/hyphenat.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/needspace/needspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginfix/marginfix.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sidenotes/sidenotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-koma.sto)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chngcntr/chngcntr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footnotebackref/footnotebackref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoc/etoc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/morewrites.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/morewrites/primargs.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bookmark.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookmark/bkm-dvipdfm.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-abspage.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zref/zref-base.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-1.mdf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/ppxetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarypositioning.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ccicons/ccicons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307
.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/dialogue.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/blkcntrl.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/frankenstein/moredefs.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/tracklang.sty' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/tracklang.sty/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/bidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/bidi/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/luabidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/luabidi/after' instead.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
Writing index file lane2.idx
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrhack.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/floatrow.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/listings.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/nomencl.hak)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/setspace.hak))

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4paper,fontsize,twoside].

(./lane2.aux

LaTeX Warning: Label `eq:pyth' multiply defined.

)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/fr-longtable.sty)
No file lane2.toc.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdflscape/pdflscape.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/lscape.hak))

Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown mtocsection defaults to 0.


(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd) [1] (./lane2.mw)
Overfull \hbox (0.26108pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 121--123
[]\TU/LibertinusSerif(0)/m/n/10 There were some other people present and one of
 them

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 131.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 131.

! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \mitlambda 
l.131 I
        didn't care to rewrite Henk's email in \LaTeX\ notation.
?
```

Comment: please fix your question to include an example `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Henk Barendregt book on $\lambda$-calculus}
\end{document}`  has no error

Comment: that is an open problem in hyperref https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/63. You will have to use \texorpdfstring to replace the \lambda by something hyperref can handle.